# How to get the mail content from any xml file

Tags: node.js, xml, email, express, nodemailer

I am using nodemailer in my mean stack applicaion. I am sending successfully mails using it.

Now I am trying to send the mail by depending upon the situation. For this I am storing the mail content in xml page and i need to get that mail content depending upon the key word in the html tag of nodemailer.

For ex: If a user registered then registration mail will be sent by getting registration key word in xml file.

XML file as shown below

```
   <?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<MailContent>
  <registration>
    <AfterSignUp>
     <html><body><p>
      Hello #FirstName #LastName
     </p>
      <p>
      <br/>
      You recently registered for #ProjectName.To complete your registration, please <a href="#URL">Click Here </a> to confirm 'your' account.
      </p> 
     <br/>
      <p>
      Warm Regards,
      </p>
      <br/>
      <p>
      System Administrator
      </p>
      <br/>
      <p>
      #ProjectName.
      </p></body></html></AfterSignUp>
    <SignUpSubject>Registration confirmation for #ProjectName</SignUpSubject>
  </registration>

  <ForgotPassword>
    <ForgetContent><html><body><p>
      Hello #FirstName #LastName
      </p>
      <p>
      You have requested to have your password reset for your account at #ProjectName.
      </p>
      <p>
      Click the below link to reset your account password
      </p>
      <p>
      <a href="#URL">Reset Password </a>
      </p>
      <br/>
       <p>
      Warm Regards,
      </p>
      <br/>
      <p>
      System Administrator
      </p>
      <br/>
      <p>
       #ProjectName.
      </p></body></html></ForgetContent>
    <ForgetSubject>#ProjectName password recovery.</ForgetSubject>
  </ForgotPassword>

</MailContent>
```

Node mailer mailoptions as below

```
    let mailOptions = {
    from: 'mailid', // sender address
    to: 'mailid', // list of receivers
    subject:, // Subject line

    html: '' // html body
};
```

In above how to get that xml file content in nodemailer options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by using handlebars and fs to render the html page by referring the [Nodemailer](https://community.nodemailer.com/2-0-0-beta/templating/) for quick solving.

I have created the registrationcontent.html and render it in node mailer as below

```
 var readHTMLFile = function (path, callback) {
                        fs.readFile(path, { encoding: 'utf-8' }, function (err, html) {
                            if (err) {
                                throw err;
                                callback(err);
                            }
                            else {
                                callback(null, html);
                            }
                        });
                    };

                    console.log("Sending", user, done);
                    var smtpConfig = {
                        host: mailconfig.host,
                        port: mailconfig.port,
                        auth: {
                            user: mailconfig.USER,
                            pass: mailconfig.PASSWORD
                        }

                    };
                    console.log(smtpConfig);
        var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpConfig);

     readHTMLFile(__dirname + '/../MailContents/mail.html', function (err, html) {
                        var template = handlebars.compile(html);
                        var replacements = {
                            FirstName: user.FirstName,
                            LastName: user.LastName,
            URL :`http://sample.com`
                            };
                        var htmlToSend = template(replacements);
                        var mailOptions = {
                            to: user.Email,
                            from: 'mail',
                            subject: 'Registration confirmation',
                            html: htmlToSend
                        };
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (err) => {
     console.log("An e-mail has been sent to with further instructions.");
     res.json("Thank you for registering. An Email has been sent to you. Go to registered email inbox to complete the registration process.");
                            done(err);
                        });
                    });
```

For Quick solution i have done with separate html's for every mail but i need to use only one file either xml or html or any other format that contains all mail bodies in one file and can be fetched by key word.

```
Any solution is highly appreciated.
```

Thanks